# How to create Dialogflow login for users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

How would I go about making a user login / acocunt making for a Dialogflow agent that would consist of a username and password and then store it on firebase / firestore?

I'm making an app that will require users to login, but the app depends almost entirely on the Dialgflow agent and considering most things on Dialogflow are fairly easy, i figured this might be easier.

From what I've read, there is a way of doing this through the actions on google console, however I was hoping to use a webhook / the inline editor to make a function. I would provide a code sample of what I have tried, but truthfully I'm not even really sure where to start.

With your answer, if you could maybe provide a general code snippet I could probably build off of that.

Thank you for your help or any suggestions!

**Note**: If ultimately the actions of google route is a lot easier and better, I will go that route, I just do not want to have the dependency of the google assistant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Account linking is handled by Actions On Google, instead of in Dialogflow (though you'll still have to handle the fulfillment on your end). Dialogflow -itself- doesn't have the capability of doing any user-login flow, but can assist AoG in doing so.

Authentication comes in 3 flavors; the easiest being "Google Sign-in", which just requests a user to log in with their Google Account. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) .  The example covers your question pretty closely, and should even work using the inline-editor.

You could write your own OAuth service (which would somewhat allow you to store user credentials in firestore), but it is definitely going to be more work. More info on the AoG details [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2)